# Proftpd fails silently. The system says it's running, but it's not accepting connections

Tags: proftpd

I have installed `proftpd` on a Centos 7 machine.

This is the output of `systemctl -l status proftpd`:

```
proftpd.service - ProFTPD FTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/proftpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since gio 2017-06-15 08:46:23 EDT; 2s ago
  Process: 5358 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/proftpd $PROFTPD_OPTIONS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 5359 (proftpd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/proftpd.service
           └─5359 proftpd: (accepting connections

giu 15 08:46:23 edmure.francescoruvolo.com systemd[1]: Starting ProFTPD FTP Server...
giu 15 08:46:23 edmure.francescoruvolo.com proftpd[5359]: 64.137.242.120 - ProFTPD 1.3.5e (maint) (built Wed May 3 2017 14:58:47 UTC) standalone mode STARTUP
giu 15 08:46:23 edmure.francescoruvolo.com systemd[1]: Started ProFTPD FTP Server.
```

All `start`, `stop` and `restart` commands work fine, without displaying any error.

I checked configuration with `--testconfig` and it does not display any error. Anyway, here is the complete [`proftpd.conf`](https://pastebin.com/36nkwcFR) file, although I didn't changed any options, so it's weird that it's not working out of the box.

There are no logs in `/var/log/proftpd/`. `/var/log/messages/` only show the same lines that `systemctl status` does.

There are no firewall rules:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Still, I'm unable to use `netcat` to connect on port 21, even from localhost. And `netstat -tulpn | grep :21` does not show any output.

Here is the output of `proftpd -V`:

```
Compile-time Settings:
  Version: 1.3.5e (maint)
  Platform: LINUX [Linux 3.10.0-514.21.1.el7.x86_64 x86_64]
  Built: Wed May 3 2017 14:58:47 UTC
  Built With:
    configure  '--build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--program-prefix=' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--prefix=/usr' '--exec-prefix=/usr' '--bindir=/usr/bin' '--sbindir=/usr/sbin' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--datadir=/usr/share' '--includedir=/usr/include' '--libdir=/usr/lib64' '--libexecdir=/usr/libexec' '--localstatedir=/var' '--sharedstatedir=/var/lib' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--libexecdir=/usr/libexec/proftpd' '--localstatedir=/run/proftpd' '--disable-strip' '--enable-ctrls' '--enable-dso' '--enable-facl' '--enable-ipv6' '--enable-memcache' '--enable-nls' '--enable-openssl' '--enable-pcre' '--enable-shadow' '--enable-tests' '--with-libraries=/usr/lib64/mysql' '--with-includes=/usr/include/mysql' '--with-modules=mod_readme:mod_auth_pam:mod_tls' '--with-shared=mod_sql:mod_sql_passwd:mod_sql_mysql:mod_sql_postgres:mod_quotatab:mod_quotatab_file:mod_quotatab_ldap:mod_quotatab_radius:mod_quotatab_sql:mod_ldap:mod_ban:mod_wrap:mod_ctrls_admin:mod_facl:mod_load:mod_vroot:mod_radius:mod_ratio:mod_rewrite:mod_site_misc:mod_exec:mod_shaper:mod_geoip:mod_wrap2:mod_wrap2_file:mod_wrap2_sql:mod_copy:mod_deflate:mod_ifversion:mod_qos:mod_sftp:mod_sftp_pam:mod_sftp_sql:mod_tls_shmcache:mod_tls_memcache:mod_ifsession' 'build_alias=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' 'host_alias=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' 'CFLAGS=-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1  -m64 -mtune=generic' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-z,relro -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld' 'CXXFLAGS=-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1  -m64 -mtune=generic'

  CFLAGS: -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1  -m64 -mtune=generic -Wall
  LDFLAGS: -L$(top_srcdir)/lib -Wl,-z,relro -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld -L/usr/lib64/mysql -L/usr/lib64/mysql -L/usr/lib64
  LIBS: -lacl  -lpcreposix -lpcre -lssl -lcrypto -lssl -lcrypto -lcap  -lmemcached -lmemcachedutil  -lssl -lcrypto  -lpam -lsupp -lcrypt -ldl 

  Files:
    Configuration File:
      /etc/proftpd.conf
    Pid File:
      /run/proftpd/proftpd.pid
    Scoreboard File:
      /run/proftpd/proftpd.scoreboard
    Header Directory:
      /usr/include/proftpd
    Shared Module Directory:
      /usr/libexec/proftpd

  Features:
    - Autoshadow support
    + Controls support
    + curses support
    - Developer support
    + DSO support
    + IPv6 support
    + Largefile support
    - Lastlog support
    + Memcache support
    + ncursesw support
    + NLS support
    + OpenSSL support (FIPS enabled)
    + PCRE support
    + POSIX ACL support
    + Shadow file support
    + Sendfile support
    + Trace support

  Tunable Options:
    PR_TUNABLE_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
    PR_TUNABLE_DEFAULT_RCVBUFSZ = 8192
    PR_TUNABLE_DEFAULT_SNDBUFSZ = 8192
    PR_TUNABLE_GLOBBING_MAX_MATCHES = 100000
    PR_TUNABLE_GLOBBING_MAX_RECURSION = 8
    PR_TUNABLE_HASH_TABLE_SIZE = 40
    PR_TUNABLE_NEW_POOL_SIZE = 512
    PR_TUNABLE_SCOREBOARD_BUFFER_SIZE = 80
    PR_TUNABLE_SCOREBOARD_SCRUB_TIMER = 30
    PR_TUNABLE_SELECT_TIMEOUT = 30
    PR_TUNABLE_TIMEOUTIDENT = 10
    PR_TUNABLE_TIMEOUTIDLE = 600
    PR_TUNABLE_TIMEOUTLINGER = 30
    PR_TUNABLE_TIMEOUTLOGIN = 300
    PR_TUNABLE_TIMEOUTNOXFER = 300
    PR_TUNABLE_TIMEOUTSTALLED = 3600
    PR_TUNABLE_XFER_SCOREBOARD_UPDATES = 10
```

I'm lost and have no idea about how to further troubleshoot the problem. I have also removed and reinstalled the package, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Does your server have free RAM available?

Comment: @atrias Sure! The server has no resource problem! It has 3Gb of RAM and currently uses about 1Gb!

Comment: Can you successfully start `proftpd` directly on the command-line, rather than using `systemctl`, and have it listen/handle connections?

Answer (score 0):

So your config file is syntactically correct, since it doesn't complain while using --testconfig or initialization. Since the service starts cleanly and doesn't complain, it's either not attempting to bind to 21 or is losing it shortly after.

Not sure if it's necessary per your build version, but I noticed you don't have the Port directive inserted in your config. Have you tried adding: `Port    21` towards the top of your config? Not sure if it's treating the lack of it as `Port 0`, which disables the server.

http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_Port.html